# Find a vector whose length is 1 given some inner product?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inner-products

I am given a space with inner product $\int_{0}^{2}f(x)g(x)dx$ and told to find a vector of length 1. I know that the length of a vector is $\sqrt{a*a}$, so this one would be set up as $1=\sqrt{\int_0^2f(g)^2dx} $  which can be simplified to $1^2=\int_0^2f(g)^2dx$.

Is this set up correctly? If so, how do I go about solving this?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be $\sqrt{\int_0^2 f(x)^2\,dx}$. Just take any nonzero element and divide it by its norm (length as you called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diven any function $g:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ with  non-zero  norm $\|g\|$, one can define the function $f [9,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x)=\lambda g(x),
$$
where $\lambda=1/\|g\|$.

Then
$$
\|f\|=\|\lambda g\|=\lambda \||g\|=\frac{\||g\|}{\|g\|}=1
$$

For instance, if $g: [0.2] \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$g(x)=\sqrt{2-x}$, then
$$
\|g\|=\sqrt{\int_0^2(2-x)dx}=\sqrt{[2x-0.5x^2]_0^2}=\sqrt{2}
$$
The function $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$f(x)=\sqrt{1-0.5x}$ will then have $1$ as norm .